# Error in Kleene "Introduction to Metamathematics" parentheses lemmas?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, meta-math

In the classic book, *Introduction to Metamathematics* by Steven Kleene, *Lemma 2* of Section 7 (chapter 2), seems to me to be false. I am wondering if I am missing something. Here is the context:

The following definitions are used:

**Proper pairing** - one-to-one pairing between n left parentheses "(" and n right parentheses ")" such that for each pair left parenthesis is on the left from the right parenthesis and if no two pairs separate each other.

Pairs of parentheses that **separate each other** - two pairs separate each other if they occur in the order $(_i(_j)_i)_j$ (ignoring everything else).

Then Kleene gives *Lemma 1*, stated below, which I agree with and find easy to prove using strong induction. Note that the lemma states "an" innermost pair, not "precisely one" innermost pair.

*Lemma 1*: A proper pairing of $2n$ parentheses ($n>0$ and $n$ is a natural number) contains an innermost pair, i.e. a pair which includes no other of the parentheses between them.

Then Kleene gives *Lemma 2* as follows, which I disagree with.

*Lemma 2*: A set of $2n$ parentheses admits at most one proper pairing.

Kleene gives the following explanation: "Prove by a (simple) induction on $n$. (HINT: Under the induction step by *Lemma 1* the given parentheses contain an innermost pair. Withdrawing this, the hypothesis of the induction applies to the set of the parentheses remaining."

I have a problem with this. Why? Consider $(^1_1(^2_2)^3_2)^4_1$ and $(^1_1)^2_1(^3_2)^4_2$. Each of these examples contains $2n$ parentheses, is a proper pairing, but are not the same pairing. The last sentence of Kleene's explanation does not hold because, just because the an innermost pair is removed, you can include a set of parentheses around the outside or concatenated with the current pair.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does not support your objection, since $(())$ and $()()$ are not the same string of parentheses. They are different sets, and each of them does in fact admit a single proper pairing, illustrated by the colors here: $\color{red}(\color{blue}(\color{blue})\color{red})$, and $\color{red}(\color{red})\color{blue}(\color{blue})$. Moreover, for each of them it is true that if we remove an innermost pair, what is left is a single pair that has a unique proper pairing: there is only one innermost pair in $(())$, and there are two innermost pairs in $()()$, but removing any of these innermost pairs leaves the properly paired string $()$.

Comment: Thank you @Brian! I didn't understand the definition of "set of parentheses" in this case. I now see that given n pairs (aka left / right pairs) of parentheses, the order in which they occur matters in order to constitute "the same set." So (()) can have 2 different meanings, although it won't if it's a proper pairing, as you noted and the lemma proves. So proper pairs, (()) and ()(), are "different sets" as you said, so do not apply to the hypothesis of the lemma.

Comment: @Axel: You’re welcome! Yes, I thought that that was where the confusion had probably arisen.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am having the same confusion as the OP. 

Could you explain again, please, perhaps in more detail? I am interpreting “set of parentheses” as a placement of parentheses in a formula. Is the Lemma merely trying to convey that left and right parentheses cannot be exchanged (with the pairing remaining proper)?

Comment: @Cyrus: By ‘a set of $2n$ parentheses’ Kleene actually means a *string* of $2n$ parentheses; (()) and ()() are different strings, so in his terms they count as different sets, and each of them admits exactly one proper pairing, the one that I illustrated with colors in my answer. The lemma says that if you write down any string consisting of an even number of parentheses, either there will be exactly one way to match up the left and right parentheses in a proper pairing, or there wil be no way to do so. Obviously there will be no way if you have different numbers of left and right ...

Comment: ... parentheses, but it can happen even if you have the same number of left and right parentheses: )()( has no proper pairing.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for the clarification. In that case, this Lemma more or less serves to show that our definition of proper pair always corresponds to one distinguished permutation of a set of 2n parenthesis, for every n, if I’m not mistaken?

Comment: @Cyrus: It says that each possible sequence of an even number of parentheses has either exactly one perfect pairing or none at all. For each $n>1$ there is more than one sequence of $2n$ parentheses having a proper pairing: for $n=2$ there are $2$, for $n=3$ there are five — ((())), (())(), ()(()), (()()), and ()()() — for $n=4$ there are $14$, and in general there are $C_n$ sequences that admit a proper pairing, where $C_n$ is the $n$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).